# independent parallel writing into files in C++ and MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I have implemented a code in C++ and MPI that is supposed to do millions of computations and save millions of numbers in about 7 files for each CPU working on its data. And I am using about 10,000 cores which gives a total of 70,000 files with millions lines of codes to be written in parallel.

I used ofstream for the writing but for some reason the MPI code breaks at the middle and the files seems to be empty. I want each processor to write its 7 files independently than all the other processors and according to my search this could be done using MPI but I read about it in many resources and I can't understand how can it be used for independent writing and with specifying the file names dynamically during execution. If it is the correct way can somebody please explain it with as much details as possible?  And if not please explain your other suggestion as much details as possible?

My current writing that doesn't work looks something like this:

```
if (rank == 0)
    {

    if(mkdir("Database",0777)==-1)//creating a directory
    {

    }
    rowsCount = fillCombinations(BCombinations,  RCombinations,
                                 BList,               RList,
                                 maxCombinations,        BIndexBegin, 
                                 BIndexEnd,           RIndexBegin, 
                                 RIndexEnd,    
                                 BCombinationsIndex,  RCombinationsIndex
                          );
}

//then broad cast all the arrays that will be used in all of the computations and at the root 
//send all the indexes to work on on the slaves then at the slave 

or (int cc = BeginIndex ; cc <= EndIndex; cc++)
        {


           // begin by specifying the values that will be used 
           // and making files for each B and R in the list


            BIndex      = betaCombinationsIndex   [cc];
            RIndex     = roughCombinationsIndex  [cc];



            //creating files to save data in and indicating the R and B by their index 
            //specifying files names

           std::string str1;
           std::ostringstream buffer1;
           buffer1 << "Database/";
           str1 = buffer1.str();

           //specifying file names

            std::ostringstream pFileName;
            std::string ppstr2;
            std::ostringstream ppbuffer2;
            ppbuffer2 <<"P_"<<"Beta_"<<(BIndex+1)<<"_Rho_"<<(RIndex+1)<<"_sampledP"<< ".txt";
            ppstr2 = ppbuffer2.str();
            pFileName <<str1.c_str()<<ppstr2.c_str();
            std::string p_file_name = pFileName.str();

            std::ostringstream eFileName;
            std::string eestr2;
            std::ostringstream eebuffer2;
            eebuffer2 <<"E_"<<"Beta_"<<(BIndex+1)<<"_Rho_"<<(RIndex+1)<<"_sampledE"<< ".txt";
            eestr2 = eebuffer2.str();
            eFileName <<str1.c_str()<< eestr2.c_str();
            std::string e_file_name = eFileName.str();

            // and so on for the 7 files .... 


            //creating the files
            ofstream pFile;
            ofstream eFile;

            // and so on for the 7 files .... 

            //opening the files
            pFile      .open (p_file_name.c_str());
            eFile        .open (e_file_name.c_str());

            // and so on for the 7 files .... 
            // then I start the writing in the files and at the end ...



            pFile.close();

            eFile.close();
}
// end of the segment loop
```

Comment: just for the sake of curiosity can you please tell me where you got 10,000 cores to work with ? Cores means a CPU core right ?

Comment: @RitwikG probably from one of the machines on this [list](http://www.top500.org).

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++/C libraries are not good enough to access that many files. Even BG/L/P kernel will collapse if you try to access hundreds of thousands of files at the same time, which is quite close to your number. Large number of physical files also stresses the parallel system with of extra metadata.

Sophisticated supercomputers generally have a large number of dedicated I/O nodes -- why don't you utilize the standard MPI functions for parallel I/O? That should be enough for the number of files you would like to save.

You can start here : http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man3/MPI_File_open.3.php

Good luck!

Comment: You are right I am working on BG/P ...but according to my readings the MPI open files for the entire communicator and I have one communicator ... this way I will need to open the 70,000 files at the the beginning ??

Comment: @SOSO, each file (or set of files) can be made accessible to its particular rank only by using the `MPI_COMM_SELF` communicator. This comes from the man page referenced above: "MPI_File_open opens the file identified by the filename on all processes in the comm communicator group. MPI_File_open is a collective routine; all processes must provide the same value for amode, and all processes must provide filenames that reference the same file and which are textually identical. A process can open a file independently of other processes by using the MPI_COMM_SELF communicator."

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to do the IOs by yourself? If not, you could give a try to the [HDF5 library](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/PHDF5/) which becomes quite popular among the scientists using HPC. It might be forth having a look at it, this might simplify your work. E.g. you can write things in the same file and avoid having thousands of files. (Remark that your performances might also depend on the filesystem of your cluser)

Comment: Mmm ... each file should be written alone ... its kind of creating a database that's why each lets say 60,000 values of each file should be alone ... are you saying that this can be done using HDF5 library?? if so, please send me some good websites from your experience about this ... I am reading the site you attached to me but so far I didn't find its uses and it is kind of hard to find what I am looking for ...

Comment: @SOSO : I missunderstood your question then. What is your problem exactly? I thought you wanted to avoid the creation of the 70'000 files...

Comment: I want to create the 70,000 files but for some reason they are not created ... I tried the computations without creating the files ...they seem be going well ... but when I add the file creation and writing the computation blows off ... and I can't see the reason why??

Answer (score 1):

Well create 7 threads or processes what ever you are using and append the threadid / processid to file being written. There should be no contention this way.

Comment: Hello Adnan, I am not sure I understand what you are saying ??

Answer (score 1):

The Blue Gene architecture might only have a few years left, but the problem of how to do "scalable I/O" will remain with us for some time.

First, MPI-IO is essentially a requirement at this scale, particularly the collective I/O features.  Even though this paper was written for /L, the lessons are still relevant:

- collective open lets the library set up some optimizations
- collective reads writes can be transformed into requests that line up nicely with GPFS file system block boundaries (which is important for lock management and minimizing overhead)
- the selection and placement of "I/O aggregators" can be done in a way that's mindful of the machine's topology

https://press3.mcs.anl.gov/romio/2006/02/15/romio-on-blue-gene-l/

The selection of aggregators is pretty complicated on /Q but the idea is that these aggregators are selected to balance I/O over all the available "system call I/O forwarding" (ciod)  links:

https://press3.mcs.anl.gov/romio/2015/05/15/aggregation-selection-on-blue-gene/